# This.props returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm currently passing data into my component via props, and for some reason it's showing up as undefined. 
From my parent component perspective I have the following pass 2 props, `data` and `header`.

```
class ContractTable extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: []
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <TableTest
                    data={this.state.data}
                    header={[
                        {
                            name: "First Name",
                            prop: "firstName"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Last Name",
                            prop: "lastName"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Age",
                            prop: "age"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Height",
                            prop: "height"
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Address",
                            prop: "address"
                        }
                    ]}
                />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I try to grab the props and set it as my state, but when I log `this.props.data` or `this.props.header` it returns undefined. Why is this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Table,
TableBody,
TableHeader,
TableHeaderColumn,
TableRow,
TableRowColumn,
} from 'material-ui/Table';

class TableTest extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: props.data,
        header: props.header
    }

    this.row = this.row.bind(this);
}

row = (currentValue, index, header) => (
    <TableRow key={`t-${index}`}>
        {
            header.map((headerName, index) => (
                <TableRowColumn key={`trc-${index}`}>
                    {currentValue[headerName.prop]}
                </TableRowColumn>
            ))
        }
    </TableRow>
);

render() {
    return 'hello'
}
}

export default TableTest;
```

Comment: Have you checked that `this.state.data` in your first component is actually defined?

Comment: Always use setState to set a state, this.state = something is incorrect and try moving setting-the-state part in componentWillMount.

Comment: setting state with a `=` operator in the constructor is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Chris Yes, it's defined in my first component

Comment: @AanchalSharma I'm pretty sure you can define state in the constructor using `=` , correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If it is possible create one demo for this.

Comment: @JorahFriendzone Can you take a look here, https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1923

Comment: @JorahFriendzone I'm sorry, you're right. :)

Comment: Could you create a code snippet or post it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)? Also, you render `hello` insted of what? Row? Rows?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** take a look https://jsfiddle.net/nroLmghv/

Just rendered simple table header.

*Passing props to state is not a good approach.*

---

I created a snippet. And it looks working. Point in which place do you have a problem. Or provide `MuiThemeProvider` and `TableTest` full code.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)       
        this.state = {
            // mock value
            data: "some value"
        }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <TableTest
         data={this.state.data}
         header={[
        {
            name: "First Name",
            prop: "firstName"
        },
        {
            name: "Last Name",
            prop: "lastName"
        },
        {
            name: "Age",
            prop: "age"
        },
        {
            name: "Height",
            prop: "height"
        },
        {
            name: "Address",
            prop: "address"
        }
    ]}
    />
    </div>;
  }
}

class TableTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data,
            header: this.props.header
        }  
    
        console.log(this.state.data)
        console.log(this.state.header)
    }
  
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried both without using this, and using this. Still returns undefined.

Comment: Here, `props.xxx` is the same as `this.props.xxx` since `super(props)` was invoked. Don't know why this was upvoted - this is not the solution at all.

Comment: I updated my code to have the entire codebase. Still not working on my end

Comment: Updated. Take a look at jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Its an antipattern to set a state that is directly derivable from props, you would rather use the props directly. Also if you use the props to set state and you need to update state based on props change, you would also need to implement `componentWillReceiveProps` function

Comment: The reason I tried to set it as state was because when I called it later in the code with `props.data` it didn't work. I was setting it to state to test.

Comment: I agree with point (2) - though point (1) is incorrect (if you mean it is incorrect to do `this.props`) since `super(props)` is invoked

Comment: So I'm supposed to have `componentWillReceiveProps` inside my child component or my parent component? And why exactly is this needed?